# How to make "undo" action in Snackbar?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-snackbar

I saw in a lot of apps the feature "undo", i.e. when the user saves a something in the database and editor has been closed, he watches `Snackbar` with "undo" action for some time.
How to show `Snackbar` I know, of course... But I can't get how to make "undo" behavior correct?
The first idea that I had it's rollback the last transaction in SQLite database... But before I can show `Snackbar` I need to load another data to show on the screen, so it won't be the last transaction already.
Can a someone explain a bit how do developers doing it in normal apps? I'm a noobie in this.
**P.S.** I must to show this snackbar in another (main) activity when the editor has been closed already.
**P.P.S.** I don't ask any code, just explanation or link where I can read about it.

Comment: Save the id/old data of that transaction and if the user clicks undo, use that id to revert back to the old data.

Comment: @PrerakSola, I didn't know that I can rollback a transaction by ID, I am a noobie in SQL. Thank you very much! I will search it.

Comment: Committed transactions do no longer exist as a separate entity. Anyway, see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/undoredo.html).

Comment: @CL., thank you for link!